# Video freezing in iphone 6 swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, ios12

I have captured the video for 5 seconds and the video should be in an encrypted format in the local storage of an app. So that I am using RNEncryptor framework for encrypting the video. But sometimes when I click use video button app get a freeze. check my code below for encrypt.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        let encryptData = try? RNCryptor.encrypt(data: data!, withPassword: "ABC123")
        do {
            try encryptData?.write(to: url!, options:.withoutOverwriting)
            self.encryptVideoData = encryptData as! NSData
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.encryptVideoData, forKey: "passportVidKey")
        } catch { // handle error
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be performing this action inside the background queue instead of main queue. And don't use force unwrap for optionals instead safely unwrap with `guard` or `if let`. statements. Below example can help,

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    guard
        let data = data,
        let url = url,
        let encryptData = try? RNCryptor.encrypt(data: data, withPassword: "ABC123")
        else { return }
    do {
        try encryptData?.write(to: url, options:.withoutOverwriting)
        self.encryptVideoData = encryptData as! NSData
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.encryptVideoData, forKey: "passportVidKey")
    } catch { // handle error
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok @kamran . I will check and let you know.